# One file startup for a many microservices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, microservices

What do you think of a single-file Startup implementation for many microservices? I have many microservices with the same configuration, if I have a microservice with a specific configuration then I would implement a specific Startup.

Comment: Perhaps you want to extract all common logic into a shared library and use it in all projects?

In .NET, you always want to think of reusable components, not reusable code files.

Comment: Yes, I have a project with the functionality but I want the opinion of the developers if a good practice or if they consider that this technique will cause some problem that I haven't thought about

Comment: Considering that .NET doesn't really provide any way to "share" code files across multiple projects, I'm not sure how you would achieve a single-file startup implementation anyway. 

If your plan is to copy the same file in all projects, you're not really sharing anything.

Comment: In my humble opinion each MicrosService should look after itself. Updating one Services startup should not effect another. However, we do use a helper library to do some default wire up as each Microservice uses NServiceBus for example and the same MessageQueue, however, they still all have their own startup file using the helper library and than add any specific needs on top if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I do use this approach for microservice projects usually.

Generally, you should figure out to which degree your services do share functionality. Let's say, all your microservices use Grpc as a framework for communication. In this case, it is perfectly valid to have a common startup in which you register dependency injection modules which provide configuration and services to enable common Grpc logic.

However, you should always allow implementers of a common Startup to have their own logic appended to it. Maybe you can just create a common base, but allow your implementers to override it and append custom logic to it.

Answer (score 1):

my solution to this, if it serves anyone:

Class abstract with Base

```
public abstract class BaseStartup
{
    #region Constructors

    protected BaseStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;
    }

    #endregion

    protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    protected IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHealthCheck(Configuration);
        services.AddExpressiveAnnotations();
        services.AddConsul(Configuration, Environment);
        services.AddApiClients(Configuration);
        services.AddConsulConfiguration(Configuration, Environment);
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
        services.AddDbContextBaseContext(Configuration);
        services.AddScrutorServiceAndRepository();
    }

    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSwagger(Environment, Configuration);
        app.UseEndpointWithHealthService();
    }
}
```

And Startup of microservice:

```
/// <summary>
/// Principal class for configuration app from net core
/// </summary>
public class Startup : BaseStartup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of Startup
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="configuration"></param>
    /// <param name="environment"></param>
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment) : base(configuration, environment)
    {
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// IoC of .NET Core for inject dependecy injection 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        base.ConfigureServices(services);
        services.AddSwagger(configuration: Configuration,
                            assemblyName: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
                            baseDirectory: AppContext.BaseDirectory);
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(TsrAutoMapperConfig).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Principal method load all configuration and runing the app
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(Environment);
        app.UseLogActivityMiddleware(nameof(ApiIngestTSR));
        app.UseLogExceptionMiddleware(Environment, nameof(ApiIngestTSR));
        base.Configure(app);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is if you need to register something at a certain point - eg. before HttpClient or after Authorization.

Comment: Also, how do you "distribute" your BaseStartup to your microservices? 
Have you made a NuGet package?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a common startup which offers the very basic wiring that every microservice needs but then added functionality can be provided via extension methods on ServiceCollection and HostBuilder which can be exposed via shared libraries. We took tat approach in our microservice chassis.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on if all your services exists in one Repository you can create shared project, and use in every service.If you have Repository per service, the best solution will be creating private nuget feed and publish you shared package there, then add your private nuget feed for every service and use it.